# VB.Net Sqlite - Parameterized query not working

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I never asked any questions on stackoverflow but it already brought me tons of answers !
But this time, after some extended research, I have to ask it myself.

I'm using VB.Net with Sqlite and my query doesn't return any value when I execute it with parameters. I guess this has something to do with the fact `SituationString` contains commas but I really can't figure it out.

Here's is my code :

```
dim ChildCtx as Integer
dim SituationString as String

SituationString="968,970,978,979,980,981,995,1022,1099,1119"

With DataBase

    .SQL_CMD.Parameters.Clear()
    .SQL_CMD.CommandText = "SELECT SERVCTX_NO FROM SERVCTX WHERE SERVCTX_NO IN (@situationstring) AND MASTER = '1'"
    .SQL_CMD.Parameters.Add("@situationstring", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = SituationString
    ChildCtx = .SQL_CMD.ExecuteScalar
    .SQL_CMD.Parameters.Clear()

End with
```

Connection is open and query works out fine if I write the whole query into one string.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two techincs: merging constant data into SQL command and using parameters to pass data.

I suppose `SituationString` is a list of integer you expect for `SERVCTX_NO`.

So, you must merge it into statement:

```
.SQL_CMD.CommandText = "SELECT SERVCTX_NO FROM SERVCTX WHERE SERVCTX_NO IN ("+SituationString+") AND MASTER = '1'"
ChildCtx = .SQL_CMD.ExecuteScalar
```

Using parameters, as you did, `SERVCTX_NO` would be expected to be a string with `968,970,978,979,980,981,995,1022,1099,1119` exact content!

Comment: You mean that `Situationstring` being added as a Varchar(255) parameter the select does not return any value since it's comparing integers like `968` with the whole `968,970,978,979,980,981,995,1022,1099,1119` string ?